# Silverlight 3 Offline Mode

Tags: .net, silverlight, installation

Has anyone found that the userbase is more reluctant to install Silverlight 3 Apps in offline mode because they have no control over "where" the app is installed to?  I've had a few issues of a similar nature in the past, with 'power users' getting upset that they can't specify install directories.  Are there any workarounds?  Any way to get the Silverlight offline installs to prompt for specific install locations and the like?

The specific reason given is that users want to install apps to remote storage, like a USB stick or something.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't ever had that problem before with similar technologies (such as ClickOnce).  In fact I've found the opposite.  In general users are more comfortable with software if they have to answer less questions.

For the majority of users out there they simply don't care where an app is installed to.  And most don't even understand the consequences of choosing one location over another.

Why burden users with choices they don't care about and can't answer in a meaningful way?  I know it's not true of every user, but IMHO, it is for the majority.

Comment: I had this exact problem with ClickOnce.  People were very upset at the 'underhandedness' of the application not being 'easy to find' on their hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

GWLlosa -- really, you're getting that type of feedback.  That's surprising.  But you do mention power users.  Given that I'll offer this.  First, you can install the shortcut to the desktop and/or the start menu.  That gives a point to start the application.

Second in a world where operating systems rely so much less on *where* things are as long as they are discoverable, I'd add that Silverlight out-of-browser experiences show up in the Vista/Win7/Desktop Search triggers on Windows and Spotlight search on Mac.  I'd argue that a true power user is already using this function.  I can't remember the last time I clicked the start menu to access the program files group!

Answer (score 0):

I think this argument is analogous to being unhappy with where your temporary internet files are stored. You’re obviously talking about an app which runs either in or out of browser so where do the “power users” think it’s running from when it’s in the browser? It still needs to download before it executes locally. Perhaps this question might put things back in context.